# how can i display the actual input from the user even after arithmetic operations?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

```
const int SCND_TO_HOUR = 3600, SCND_TO_MINUTE = 60; //constant declaration
int seconds,hour,minute,remainSeconds;
cout << "Input the total time in seconds : " << endl;
cin >> seconds;
hour = seconds / SCND_TO_HOUR;
seconds = seconds % SCND_TO_HOUR;
minute = seconds / SCND_TO_MINUTE;
seconds = seconds % SCND_TO_MINUTE;
remainSeconds = seconds;
```

//the display is suppossed to be *user input* seconds are equals to ....
cout << seconds << " seconds are equals to " << hour << " hours " << minute << " minutes and " << remainSeconds<< "seconds" << endl;

Comment: Use a separate variable for the original input that you don't modify. Actually, you alreayd have both `seconds` and `remainSeconds`, so instead of overwriting `seconds`, just write directly to `remainSeconds`.

Comment: Unrelated recommendation: Don't comment the obvious stuff. It just adds clutter.